# Does Jinx increase the additional damage of Hex to 20% or 30%?

Tags: diablo-iii, diablo-iii-witch-doctor

The description of the Jinx rune is a little unclear, and therefore I'm uncertain if it increases the additional damage of Hex by 20% to a total of 30%, or if it only increases it by 10% to a total of 20%.

[image]

How much does Jinx increase the additional damage buff provided by Hex?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It should be 20%. Other runes, like Several Sided Strike (9 hits on Seven-Sided Strike), which are worded similarly do not mean original + rune (it's 9 hits, not 16), and Jinx should be no exception. It modifies the last sentence from "hexed targets... take 10% additional damage" to "hexed targets ... take 20% additional damage".

If it was 30%, the tooltip would most likely read, "Hexed targets take **an** additional 20% damage".